# Setting Screen Density in at build time for custom AOSP builds

Tags: android, android-source

I am currently working on a custom rom based on Android 9 source code for an Android tablet. We can currently set the screen density at run time via adb like so:

> adb shell wm density value_in_pixels

However we will need to set this value as the image is *being built*. Having done a bit of research I believe it's going to be a build property somewhere but I cannot for the life of me figure out where the property is, or if it needs to be added, where that should be added to. Grateful for any assistance if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 4):

Add ro.sf.lcd_density in the product's [device.mk](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/linaro/dragonboard/pixel3_mainline/device.mk;l=39?q=ro.sf.lcd_density&start=11).

```
PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += \
    ro.sf.lcd_density=xxx
```

And set PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG and PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG to include the right resources.

```
PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG := hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi
PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG := xhdpi
```

Comment: I just wanted to drop a quick comment to say thanks for getting back @Yong. I haven't quite had a chance to try it just yet!

Comment: this did the trick, thanks for your help!